# How do I SELECT rows using DATEDIFF?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm using [this calendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/usage/) plugin to display my client's agenda using a mySQL db.
The calendar POSTs a request to my script with a `start` and `end` UNIX timestamp like this:

```
/getevents.php?start=1262332800&end=1265011200&_=1263178646
//That last piece of data is to prevent caching.. apparently
```

In my script, I convert the UNIX timestamps to mySQL `datetime` objects like this:

```
$start = $_GET['start'];
$end = $_GET['end'];
$start = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", $start);
$end = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", $end);
printf($start.".....".$end);
```

This correctly prints something like the following (when I navigate to September 2012):

```
2012-08-26 04:00:00.....2012-10-07 04:00:00
```

Now I want to select all events from my database that fall between those dates. My database has only 1 row, and the `start` field is today's date:

```
 id     start                   end
 10     2012-09-05 20:27:00     0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

But with the following SQL statement, I don't get a result. I've tried inverting the `>` to `<` just for the hell of it, but still nothing. I'm not getting any errors at all, just no results.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM all_events WHERE DATEDIFF('$start', 'start') > 0";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $link) or die(mysql_error());
echo "Rows:".mysql_num_rows($result);
```

As you can see, right now I'm just checking that the `start` of the event is greater than the `start` of the calendar's date range.. ie August 26th is the `start` for the month of September.

I don't see anything wrong... help please! I'm tearing my hair out!

Comment: "SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATEDIFF($end, $start) > 0" ie some positive number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `single quotes` for column name but instead use `backticks`.try this

```
SELECT * FROM all_events WHERE DATEDIFF(`start`, '$start') > 0
```

Comment: *facepalm* I hate it when things are this simple! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use `FROM_UNIXTIME` and prepared statements like so:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM all_events WHERE DATEDIFF(FROM_UNIXTIME(?), start) > 0"); 
$stmt->bind_param($_GET['start']);
```

`mysql_` functions are being [deprecated](http://www.deprecatedphp.com/mysql)

Comment: I'm aware that the `mysql_` functions are deprecated.. I tried using `mysqli_` which only severely flustered my code. I'm going to try and get things running for my client at least, then worry about updating. Thanks for the info, though!